# Can someone please explain this sed command to me?

Tags: sed

`sed -n '/aaaa/{:a;n;/zzzz/b;p;ba}'`

In context:

`echo "aaaa\nsometext\nzzzz\n" | sed -n '/aaaa/{:a;n;/zzzz/b;p;ba}'`

prints "**sometext**", which is correct and expected, but I don't understand the syntax, despite staring at a sed cheatsheet for a while.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free consulting/design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)*

Comment: Hm. Doesn't work for me in my mingw console.

Comment: There should be literally thousands of examples available from a web search of how to use the `sed` command and how to interpret the replacement string in your example.

Comment: It works for me. I copy and paste the above into a bash or zsh shell and it works.

Comment: Basically, you need to ask a question, which you aren't doing. So provide the full context and the full question, as well as you can. But before you do any of that, see if anyone else ran into the same problem. Maybe, "How does sed work"? Stuff like that. There's a section here called Documentation which you might find really helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution#t=201707101842341063015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed reads the current line into its pattern space. Typically, sed prints the pattern space after processing current line. This can be disabled with option `-n`. sed thus outputs its pattern space only with the command `p`.

Only if sed finds a line which contains somewhere expression `aaaa` it executes commands in curley brackets.

`:a` is a label with name `a` and has no effect. With command `n` sed reads the next line of input into its pattern space. `aaaa` is overwritten in pattern space. If pattern space now contains expression `zzzz` execute command `b` and branch to end of script and end execution. If pattern space does not contain expression `zzzz` execute `p` (print pattern space) and execute command `ba` (jump to label `a`). And start again with command `n` ...